# "There is something in something" vs "something has something"

Tags: sentence-patterns

How can I know which type of the sentence I should use:
"There is something in something"

or

"something has something"?

For example, (taken from Duolingo but slightly changed):

- There are statues in the temples.
- The temples have statues.

Is it bad if I always use the first type? I ask because in my language it sounds a little weird when an inanimate thing has (owns) something. Yet this is correct on Duolingo, which often offers the second type.

Are they interchangeable or is one of them more correct?

Comment: Both sentence types are quite acceptable. While they are synonymous, there _is_ a slight change in emphasis, with the first sentence foregrounding the statues, and the second more unmarked (equal prominence). // This sense of 'have' is more like that used in 'John has measles' than 'John has [owns] a red bike.' It stands in for 'is suffering from' / 'contains' / 'is accompanied by' ('The piano had a stool') ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks a lot!